# Force iron-router to go to current route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have created a route like:

```
this.route('design.create', {
    path: '/design',
    template: 'Design',
```

I have wroten some **waitOn, data, onBeforeAction, onStop** related and executed when the route is loaded.

I have a "strange" use case: 
Where I'm already in the route **design.create** I would like **re-init** it (execute again waitOn, data, onBeforeAction, onStop).

A simple: Router.go('design.create') not works...I guess because I'm already on the same route.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that:

```
Router.current()._computation.invalidate()
```

Do what I want...but it's not very elegant call a private method

Answer (score 0):

Set a dependency by using a session variable in the onBeforeAction and change the session variable when you what the current route to get rerun:

```
...
onBeforeAction: function() {
    Session.get('dependOnMe')
    // the acutal onBeforeAction-code goes here
}
...

...
// somewhere else
Session.set('dependOnMe', new Date())
// will trigger the onBeforeAction again
...
```